# Find the codomain of the random variable defined as the sum of independent Poisson and Binomial random variables

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have this exercise:

Let :
$\begin{array}{lcl} X & \sim & Po(\lambda_1), \\ Y & \sim & Po(\lambda_2), \\ Z & \sim & Bin(1, \frac{1}{2})  \end{array}$
be independent random variables, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 > 0$.
Consider $T := (X+Y)Z-1$

Determine the codomine of $T$.
If $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 2$ determine the probability function of $T$.

---

I have tried but without success to do it. Here we have that:
$\begin{array}{lcl} X & \sim & Po(1), \\ Y & \sim & Po(2), \\ Z & \sim & Bin(1, \frac{1}{2})  \end{array}$
therefore, I have considered the probability function for each random var
$\begin{array}{lcl}P(X=x) & = & e^{-1} \frac{1^x}{x!} & \mbox{for} & x = 0, \dots, +\infty \\ P(Y = y) & = & e^{-2} \frac{2^y}{y!} & \mbox{for} & y = 0, \dots, +\infty \\ P(Z = z) & = & \binom{1}{z}(\frac{1}{2})^{1-z}(\frac{1}{2})^z & \mbox{for} & z = 0, \dots, 1  \end{array}$

but, from here, please can you tell me how can I continue? Thanks!

Comment: What is $n$ in your attempts?

Comment: Do you know that the codomain is? Can you point out the codomain of, say, $X$? Are you asking about the first and/or the second part of the problem?

Comment: I have edited what I have done. I ask for both parts.

Comment: $Z$ can be only $0$ or $1$, then what are the possible values of $T$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis if I'm right, if $Z=0$ then $T = -1$, if $Z=1$ then $T=X+Y-1$

Comment: $X+Y-1$ is not a value, it is a random variable. A random variable randomly takes some values. Which values can $X+Y-1$ take? Finding the codomain is nothing but answering this question.

Comment: Ok, but, I am not able to answer to this question, sorry. How can I know the values $X$ and $Y$ take? I know that if $X \sim Po(1) \mbox{ and } Y \sim Po(2)$ then $X+Y \sim Po(1+2) \sim Po(3)$